# In Rails, should I create a new controller action if only the response body varies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm refactoring an app that has multiple views that utilize a single controller action for different aspects of the same data (tabular, calendar, another calendar, file export)

Presently, the action uses parameters and conditions to select one of 4 responses, but the actual data is common to all 4.

Is there a general practice for this case? It seems like the simplest thing is to break this action up into 4 actions and keep it DRY with filters and private methods.

Comment: Other simple approach can be to have standardized file names for your views like marketing_tabular.html, marketing_calendar.html, marketing_other_calendar.html and render them without conditionals, if known type `render "marketing_#{params[:type]}"` else render 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your point.

Put them all in one action is not so DRY actually. Processing params with condition, preparing template name, preparing query strings in view, these all need unnecessary code comparing with split actions.

Another drawback is filters and action messages. Splitting to several actions, the `action_name` is different and then different message can be sent.

For example, I have one app which has `vote` method for one model. I ended up using `vote_up` and `vote_down` because only signed in user are allowed to vote down, then correct action_name can be sent to CanCan.